# Creating a nested Dto to return data where the composite key is present in an array

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, dto, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm attempting to create a Dto that will map a lot of nested data based off of user inputted parameters from the Web App front-end.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData(int? version,
                                             int[] subSpecialty,
                                             int[] pathway,
                                             int[] job,
                                             int[] opActivity,
                                             int[] pointOfDelivery,
                                             int[] theatreList)
```

The user input allows for multiple of a single parameter to be inputted to map multiple entries of a table therefore the parameters are taken as Arrays.

I've had a few attempts at mapping this data unsuccessfully, my current attempt feels like it should work and looks like this:

```
var dto = await
            _dbContext.ModelVersion
            .Where(mv => version == mv.Id)
            .Select(mv => new DataGetDto
            {
                ModelId = mv.Id,
                SubSpecialtyDto = mv.SubSpecialties
                                    .Where(ss => ss.ModelId == version && subSpecialty.Contains(ss.SubSpecialtyTypeId))
                                    .Select(ss => new SubSpecialtyDto
                                    {
                                        CostOp = ss.CostOp,
                                        CostTh = ss.CostTh,
                                        ModelId = ss.ModelId,
                                        SubSpecialtyTypeId = ss.SubSpecialtyTypeId,
                                        FacilityActivityDto = mv.FacilityActivities
                                                                .Where(fa => fa.ModelId == version && pointOfDelivery.Contains(fa.PointOfDeliveryId) && pathway.Contains(fa.PathwayId) && subSpecialty.Contains(fa.SubSpecialtyTypeId))
                                                                .Select(fa => new FacilityActivityDto
                                                                {
                                                                    PatientCases = fa.PatientCases,
                                                                    AverageIncome = fa.AverageIncome,
                                                                    CostToBookSinglePatient = fa.CostToBookSinglePatient,
                                                                    AverageCaseTime = fa.AverageCaseTime,
                                                                    PoDproportion = fa.PoDproportion,
                                                                    LengthOfStay = fa.LengthOfStay,
                                                                    PatientHandlingCost = fa.PatientHandlingCost,
                                                                    CostPerDay = fa.CostPerDay,
                                                                    BedOccupancy = fa.BedOccupancy,
                                                                    InplantCost = fa.InplantCost,
                                                                    OverHead = fa.OverHead,
                                                                    ModelId = fa.ModelId,
                                                                    PointOfDeliveryId = fa.PointOfDeliveryId,
                                                                    PathwayId = fa.PathwayId,
                                                                    SubSpecialtyTypeId = fa.SubSpecialtyTypeId
                                                                }),
                                        OutPatientActivityDto = mv.OutPatientActivities
                                                                  .Where(opa => opa.ModelId == version && opActivity.Contains(opa.ActivityId) && pathway.Contains(opa.PathwayId) && subSpecialty.Contains(opa.SubSpecialtyTypeId))
                                                                  .Select(opa => new OutPatientActivityDto
                                                                  {
                                                                      PatientsSeenOp = opa.PatientsSeenOp,
                                                                      AverageIncomeOp = opa.AverageIncomeOp,
                                                                      ConversionRate = opa.ConversionRate,
                                                                      ModelId = opa.ModelId,
                                                                      ActivityId = opa.ActivityId,
                                                                      PathwayId = opa.PathwayId,
                                                                      SubSpecialtyTypeId = opa.SubSpecialtyTypeId
                                                                  }),
                                        OutPatientOperationalFactorDto = mv.OutPatientOperationalFactors
                                                                           .Where(opof => opof.ModelId == version && opActivity.Contains(opof.ActivityId) && subSpecialty.Contains(opof.SubSpecialtyTypeId))
                                                                           .Select(opof => new OutPatientOperationalFactorDto
                                                                           {
                                                                               BookingRateOp = opof.BookingRateOp,
                                                                               DnarateOp = opof.DnarateOp,
                                                                               PatientCancellationRateOp = opof.PatientCancellationRateOp,
                                                                               HospitalCancellationRateOp = opof.HospitalCancellationRateOp,
                                                                               PatientLateNoticeRateOp = opof.PatientLateNoticeRateOp,
                                                                               HospitalLateNoticeRateOp = opof.HospitalLateNoticeRateOp,
                                                                               CostToBookSingleOutPatient = opof.CostToBookSingleOutPatient,
                                                                               ModelId = opof.ModelId,
                                                                               ActivityId = opof.ActivityId,
                                                                               SubSpecialtyTypeId = opof.SubSpecialtyTypeId
                                                                           }),
                                        SkillMixDistributionDto = mv.SkillMixDistributions
                                                                    .Where(smd => smd.ModelId == version && opActivity.Contains(smd.JobTypeId) && pathway.Contains(smd.PathwayId) && subSpecialty.Contains(smd.SubSpecialtyTypeId))
                                                                    .Select(smd => new SkillMixDistributionDto
                                                                    {
                                                                        WorkingWeeksPerYearOp = smd.WorkingWeeksPerYearOp,
                                                                        WorkingWeeksPerYearTh = smd.WorkingWeeksPerYearTh,
                                                                        CostPerPa = smd.CostPerPa,
                                                                        DistributionOp = smd.DistributionOp,
                                                                        DistributionTh = smd.DistributionTh,
                                                                        AdminTimeOp = smd.AdminTimeOp,
                                                                        SetupTimeOp = smd.SetupTimeOp,
                                                                        CacheUpTimeOp = smd.CacheUpTimeOp,
                                                                        PatientFacingTimeOp = smd.PatientFacingTimeOp,
                                                                        ModelId = smd.ModelId,
                                                                        JobTypeId = smd.JobTypeId,
                                                                        PathwayId = smd.PathwayId,
                                                                        SubSpecialtyTypeId = smd.SubSpecialtyTypeId,

                                                                    }),
                                        TheatreListStructureDto = mv.TheatreListStructures
                                                                    .Where(tls => tls.ModelId == version && opActivity.Contains(tls.TheatreListTypeId) && pathway.Contains(tls.SubSpecialtyTypeId))
                                                                    .Select(tls => new TheatreListStructureDto
                                                                    {
                                                                        PreOpWardRound = tls.PreOpWardRound,
                                                                        PostOpWardRound = tls.PostOpWardRound,
                                                                        FacingPatientTime = tls.FacingPatientTime,
                                                                        BreakTime = tls.BreakTime,
                                                                        PreferredSessionType = tls.PreferredSessionType,
                                                                        ModelId = tls.ModelId,
                                                                        TheatreListTypeId = tls.TheatreListTypeId,
                                                                        SubSpecialtyTypeId = tls.SubSpecialtyTypeId
                                                                    }),
                                        TheatreOperationalFactorDto = mv.TheatreOperationalFactors
                                                                        .Where(tof => tof.ModelId == version && opActivity.Contains(tof.PointOfDeliveryId) && subSpecialty.Contains(tof.SubSpecialtyTypeId))
                                                                        .Select(tof => new TheatreOperationalFactorDto
                                                                        {
                                                                            CostToRunListTh = tof.CostToRunListTh,
                                                                            PreOpAnaesthetic = tof.PreOpAnaesthetic,
                                                                            PostOpAnaesthetic = tof.PostOpAnaesthetic,
                                                                            KnifeToSkin = tof.KnifeToSkin,
                                                                            Gaps = tof.Gaps,
                                                                            LateStart = tof.LateStart,
                                                                            EarlyFinish = tof.EarlyFinish,
                                                                            InSessionUtilisation = tof.InSessionUtilisation,
                                                                            ModelId = tof.ModelId,
                                                                            PointOfDeliveryId = tof.PointOfDeliveryId,
                                                                            SubSpecialtyTypeId = tof.SubSpecialtyTypeId
                                                                        })
                                    })

            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

When I attempt to test this code I write this in the url.

```
Data?version=1&subSpecialty=1&pathway=1&job=1&opActivity=1&pointOfDelivery=1&theatreList=1
```

This happily maps the version Id (ModelId) as expected but returns an error of type System.InvalidOperationException when entering the first level of nesting:
[variable watch image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbuzz.png)

```
-       Current '((System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator<Medicor.Portal.Models.DacPlannerDtos.SubSpecialtyDto>)((Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.EnumerableAdapter<Medicor.Portal.Models.DacPlannerDtos.SubSpecialtyDto>)(new System.Collections.Generic.ICollectionDebugView<Medicor.Portal.Models.DacPlannerDtos.DataGetDto>(dto).Items[0]).SubSpecialtyDto).Results).Current' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'   Medicor.Portal.Models.DacPlannerDtos.SubSpecialtyDto {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

My Dtos are shaped in such a way that I also feel as though they are correct.

DataGetDto with the inital nested Dto:

```
public class DataGetDto
{

    public int ModelId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SubSpecialtyDto> SubSpecialtyDto { get; set; }

}
```

SubSpecialtyDto with the further nested Dtos:

```
public class SubSpecialtyDto
{
    [Range(typeof(Decimal), "0", "999999")]
    public decimal? CostOp { get; set; } //Not sure

    [Range(typeof(Decimal), "0", "999999")]
    public decimal? CostTh { get; set; } //Not sure

    public int SubSpecialtyTypeId { get; set; }

    public int ModelId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<FacilityActivityDto> FacilityActivityDto { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OutPatientActivityDto> OutPatientActivityDto { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OutPatientOperationalFactorDto> OutPatientOperationalFactorDto { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SkillMixDistributionDto> SkillMixDistributionDto { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TheatreListStructureDto> TheatreListStructureDto { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TheatreOperationalFactorDto> TheatreOperationalFactorDto { get; set; }
}
```

OutPatientActivityDto as an example of the second level nested Dtos:

```
public class OutPatientActivityDto
{
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
    public int? PatientsSeenOp { get; set; }

    [Range(typeof(Decimal), "0", "999999")]
    public decimal? AverageIncomeOp { get; set; }

    [Range(typeof(Decimal), "0", "1")]
    public decimal? ConversionRate { get; set; }

    public int ActivityId { get; set; }

    public int SubSpecialtyTypeId { get; set; }

    public int PathwayId { get; set; }

    public int ModelId { get; set; }

}
```

Therefore my questions are:

Are the Dto's structures valid?

How can the GetData Method be edited to remove the current error and map the data correctly?

If anything is too vague or missing ask and I'll be sure to add more information. Thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE**

I realised whilst re-reading my post that it may be useful to some if I attach an ERD style diagram for reference on the structure of the database [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcNPW.png).

The error is only present when debugging through Watch, there is no forced exception and when I test the code using the url a blank page is returned (I have not yet setup the view so this is expected).

Seemingly working code below using [Correlated subquery Optimisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries):

```
            var dto = 
            _dbContext.ModelVersion
            .Where(mv => version == mv.Id)
            .Select(mv => new DataGetDto
            {
                ModelId = mv.Id,
                SubSpecialtyDto = mv.SubSpecialties
                                    .Where(ss => ss.ModelId == version && subSpecialty.Contains(ss.SubSpecialtyTypeId))
                                    .Select(ss => new SubSpecialtyDto
                                    {
                                        CostOp = ss.CostOp,
                                        CostTh = ss.CostTh,
                                        ModelId = ss.ModelId,
                                        SubSpecialtyTypeId = ss.SubSpecialtyTypeId,
                                        FacilityActivityDto = mv.FacilityActivities
                                                                .Where(fa => fa.ModelId == version && pointOfDelivery.Contains(fa.PointOfDeliveryId) && pathway.Contains(fa.PathwayId) && subSpecialty.Contains(fa.SubSpecialtyTypeId))
                                                                .Select(fa => new FacilityActivityDto
                                                                {
                                                                    PatientCases = fa.PatientCases,
                                                                    AverageIncome = fa.AverageIncome,
                                                                    CostToBookSinglePatient = fa.CostToBookSinglePatient,
                                                                    AverageCaseTime = fa.AverageCaseTime,
                                                                    PoDproportion = fa.PoDproportion,
                                                                    LengthOfStay = fa.LengthOfStay,
                                                                    PatientHandlingCost = fa.PatientHandlingCost,
                                                                    CostPerDay = fa.CostPerDay,
                                                                    BedOccupancy = fa.BedOccupancy,
                                                                    InplantCost = fa.InplantCost,
                                                                    OverHead = fa.OverHead,
                                                                    ModelId = fa.ModelId,
                                                                    PointOfDeliveryId = fa.PointOfDeliveryId,
                                                                    PathwayId = fa.PathwayId,
                                                                    SubSpecialtyTypeId = fa.SubSpecialtyTypeId
                                                                }).ToList(),
                                        OutPatientActivityDto = mv.OutPatientActivities
                                                                  .Where(opa => opa.ModelId == version && opActivity.Contains(opa.ActivityId) && pathway.Contains(opa.PathwayId) && subSpecialty.Contains(opa.SubSpecialtyTypeId))
                                                                  .Select(opa => new OutPatientActivityDto
                                                                  {
                                                                      PatientsSeenOp = opa.PatientsSeenOp,
                                                                      AverageIncomeOp = opa.AverageIncomeOp,
                                                                      ConversionRate = opa.ConversionRate,
                                                                      ModelId = opa.ModelId,
                                                                      ActivityId = opa.ActivityId,
                                                                      PathwayId = opa.PathwayId,
                                                                      SubSpecialtyTypeId = opa.SubSpecialtyTypeId
                                                                  }).ToList(),
                                        OutPatientOperationalFactorDto = mv.OutPatientOperationalFactors
                                                                           .Where(opof => opof.ModelId == version && opActivity.Contains(opof.ActivityId) && subSpecialty.Contains(opof.SubSpecialtyTypeId))
                                                                           .Select(opof => new OutPatientOperationalFactorDto
                                                                           {
                                                                               BookingRateOp = opof.BookingRateOp,
                                                                               DnarateOp = opof.DnarateOp,
                                                                               PatientCancellationRateOp = opof.PatientCancellationRateOp,
                                                                               HospitalCancellationRateOp = opof.HospitalCancellationRateOp,
                                                                               PatientLateNoticeRateOp = opof.PatientLateNoticeRateOp,
                                                                               HospitalLateNoticeRateOp = opof.HospitalLateNoticeRateOp,
                                                                               CostToBookSingleOutPatient = opof.CostToBookSingleOutPatient,
                                                                               ModelId = opof.ModelId,
                                                                               ActivityId = opof.ActivityId,
                                                                               SubSpecialtyTypeId = opof.SubSpecialtyTypeId
                                                                           }).ToList(),
                                        SkillMixDistributionDto = mv.SkillMixDistributions
                                                                    .Where(smd => smd.ModelId == version && opActivity.Contains(smd.JobTypeId) && pathway.Contains(smd.PathwayId) && subSpecialty.Contains(smd.SubSpecialtyTypeId))
                                                                    .Select(smd => new SkillMixDistributionDto
                                                                    {
                                                                        WorkingWeeksPerYearOp = smd.WorkingWeeksPerYearOp,
                                                                        WorkingWeeksPerYearTh = smd.WorkingWeeksPerYearTh,
                                                                        CostPerPa = smd.CostPerPa,
                                                                        DistributionOp = smd.DistributionOp,
                                                                        DistributionTh = smd.DistributionTh,
                                                                        AdminTimeOp = smd.AdminTimeOp,
                                                                        SetupTimeOp = smd.SetupTimeOp,
                                                                        CacheUpTimeOp = smd.CacheUpTimeOp,
                                                                        PatientFacingTimeOp = smd.PatientFacingTimeOp,
                                                                        ModelId = smd.ModelId,
                                                                        JobTypeId = smd.JobTypeId,
                                                                        PathwayId = smd.PathwayId,
                                                                        SubSpecialtyTypeId = smd.SubSpecialtyTypeId,

                                                                    }).ToList(),
                                        TheatreListStructureDto = mv.TheatreListStructures
                                                                    .Where(tls => tls.ModelId == version && theatreList.Contains(tls.TheatreListTypeId) && pathway.Contains(tls.SubSpecialtyTypeId))
                                                                    .Select(tls => new TheatreListStructureDto
                                                                    {
                                                                        PreOpWardRound = tls.PreOpWardRound,
                                                                        PostOpWardRound = tls.PostOpWardRound,
                                                                        FacingPatientTime = tls.FacingPatientTime,
                                                                        BreakTime = tls.BreakTime,
                                                                        PreferredSessionType = tls.PreferredSessionType,
                                                                        ModelId = tls.ModelId,
                                                                        TheatreListTypeId = tls.TheatreListTypeId,
                                                                        SubSpecialtyTypeId = tls.SubSpecialtyTypeId
                                                                    }).ToList(),
                                        TheatreOperationalFactorDto = mv.TheatreOperationalFactors
                                                                        .Where(tof => tof.ModelId == version && pointOfDelivery.Contains(tof.PointOfDeliveryId) && subSpecialty.Contains(tof.SubSpecialtyTypeId))
                                                                        .Select(tof => new TheatreOperationalFactorDto
                                                                        {
                                                                            CostToRunListTh = tof.CostToRunListTh,
                                                                            PreOpAnaesthetic = tof.PreOpAnaesthetic,
                                                                            PostOpAnaesthetic = tof.PostOpAnaesthetic,
                                                                            KnifeToSkin = tof.KnifeToSkin,
                                                                            Gaps = tof.Gaps,
                                                                            LateStart = tof.LateStart,
                                                                            EarlyFinish = tof.EarlyFinish,
                                                                            InSessionUtilisation = tof.InSessionUtilisation,
                                                                            ModelId = tof.ModelId,
                                                                            PointOfDeliveryId = tof.PointOfDeliveryId,
                                                                            SubSpecialtyTypeId = tof.SubSpecialtyTypeId
                                                                        }).ToList()
                                    })

            });
```

Comment: First, is there a real exception **without** debugging or it happens only when you expand the result in the debugger? Second, if you are on EF Core 2.1+, you could opt-in for [Optimization of correlated subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries) by adding `ToList()` at the end of the parts which project (`Select`) enumerable dto members.

Comment: @IvanStoev I've updated my answer slightly by adding a tag and mentioning where i can see this exception. I will look into your recommendation now.

Comment: @IvanStoev Ok so I think your advice has provided the correct answer and I am correctly mapping the results. Thank you so much. I am still confused on the theory of why having everything be put to a list asynchronously causes a problem however I would be happy to accept a written answer noting your original suggestion.

Comment: I can't compose an answer, because there is no issue. The issue you are reporting is a debugger evaluation experience problem and not related to the EF Core programming. And the suggestion is just an optimization to avoid N + 1 queries, so again it's unrelated to the debugging experience. Glad that you've found it helpful though, happy coding!